# Represent recording in wave form android

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am recording heart and lung sounds using AudioRecord. I want to show this sound graphically. But literally I dont know how to do this. I was given this library to use, https://github.com/cell0907/Audio-scope. Can someone help me out with how can I transform the bytearray I capture using AudioRecord to wave form?

Thanks

Comment: this below link help u to get byte array from Audio.
http://audiorecordandroid.blogspot.in/

Comment: I know AudioRecord gets byte []. But I have to represent that in wave form. How to do that. How can I put this project as dependent project to android?